# Things to keep in mind when migrating from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, porting

So, I'll be soon working on porting two APIs (C++ and C++/CLI) to use the VS2010 compiler. I think it'd be a good idea to have a head start on this. Any tips?

Comment: Are you planning to continue targeting the same version of .NET? What version might it be?

Comment: @Ryan Versaw. Nope.
@John. C++/CLI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Breaking changes to C++/STL projects are outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx).

vs2010 will also use a different build mechanism in the for of [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx).

Unfortunately, the revamped Intellisense in [vs2010 won't extend to C++/CLI](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx) which some people aren't too happy about, however native code developer can look forward to a more responsive environment (hopefully).

Answer (score 6):

Tip #1: **it's a beta!** Don't expect RTM performance, stability, or anything else.
Tip #2: **Report bugs!** If you want it to ever stop acting like a beta, then you have to tell Microsoft about it on Connect (http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little thing worth noting. In VS2010, you have the option of specifying the target framework.